# Seeking Clarification on Indian Taxation After Resignation and Job Change

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, payroll-taxes, payroll

I recently made a career transition, resigning from an **Indian IT company** in February `2023` with my LWD in **May**. And, I was going through the last six months pay slips provided by the organization, after my LWD, for tax computations, that have left me perplexed.

I was amazed to find out that **income tax** was deducted till **March**(**Quarter-4**), but not for **April** and **May**(**Quarter-1**), in-fact there was no salary for **May**, since I guess the LWD was before their pay processing cycle for that month,  but it was paid out to me on **June** having **retro** components in it. It was a **full and final** settlement to be very precise, having basic and other components for the number of days I worked in May. It also had the **"leave encashment"** and **"Medical Insurance refund"** components in the same June month pay-slip.

I had also checked ***26AS*** form and found out that, tax deducted is `zero` and the gross total income is being correctly reflected for the quarter **Apr-Jun**.

I have some questions that I would be grateful for your help with.

- Is it common that if the **notice period falls in the starting Q1** of the year, then companies leave the taxation thing to the *employees*/*new company* where the employees joins?
- Do I need to pay **"Advance Tax"** for the period(**Q1**), or shall I leave that to the *new organization* which I joined in June end? Or, should I handle this during my ITR filing?
- Does salaried employees like me, for whom the **IT companies** deduct **TDS** month-on-month basic from the salary, needs to pay **"Advance tax"** if he/she has **"income from other sources"** like dividend, interest from FD, RD, savings account, etc. or if there wasn't any tax deducted when leaving an organization?
- Isn't the **"Leave encashment"** and **"Medical Insurance refund"** are considered to be ***tax exempted***? Should they be deducted from the ***gross total income*** and not be present in the ***net taxable income***. Are they part of ***Section 10*** exemptions and not be taken into account while showing previous income to the current employer for tax computations?

For the third question I know its kind of vague, since **"income from other sources"** can be huge, but lets just assume, my income from dividend is less than `5000` for every stocks/shares/MFs individually as well as cumulatively, but with interest income from savings banks, FD, RD, etc. exceeds `60,000` for a financial year.
I know people having income from other sources, mostly *FD/RD*, for more than `60,000` and handling them during **ITR filing**(paying `self-assessment tax`, reflected in `AIS`) but, haven't been into the **"Advance tax"** payment and there weren't any fine levied on such income, though I guess, government impose `1%` of the amount to be paid in a quarter for every months till the amount is not paid month-on-month, if **"Advance tax"** for that quarter is not being paid.
How is this possible for them in the above description to get away with the fine, if **"Advance tax"** is mandatory for all? What did I miss here?

Thanks in advance, for helping me out with these questions!

Note: For the questions asked above, you can assume my monthly salary is around `1,10,000`INR in hand. The package is around `15LPA`. Income from dividend/MFs is less than `5000`INR as of now and cumulative income from other sources is `60,000`INR
Leave encashment was of `48,000`INR and Medical insurance refund was of `1,500`INR respectively.

Comment: This a far too complicated query for this forum and it that asks multiple questions. Have you considered asking a Chartered Accountant in India for help in getting accurate answers to your questions instead of relying on advice from the Internet?

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion to consult a Chartered Accountant for accurate answers to my questions. While I understand the importance of professional advice, I currently don't have a Chartered Accountant of my own.

In the past, I've had some experiences with local CAs, and unfortunately, it wasn't as seamless as I had hoped. I often found myself having to proactively search for information and bring specific queries to their attention. While I understand that individual experiences may vary, my past encounters have left me somewhat hesitant.

Comment: Before considering reaching out to a Chartered Accountant again, I thought of exploring online forums to seek insights and guidance. However, my attempts thus far, have been met with limited success, as my questions(this and a few more) posted here, haven't been addressed yet : (